# Is the sum of convolutions of $L^1$ functions also a convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

For $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, their convolution is defined as $(f*g)(x)=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(y)g(x-y){\rm d}y$, and it is standard that $f*g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, so $*$ is an operator $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\times L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. It would be interesting to know some basic properties of the range of convolution, but it seems even not trivial to determine if this set is closed under addition: for $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, must there exist $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $$f_1*g_1+f_2*g_2 = f*g?$$ I think the tool of Fourier transform may be useful, but it is known that [$\mathcal{F}:L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\to C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not surjective](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8085), and we don't have a characterization of the range of Fourier transform. So could there be anything to say about the range of convolution of $L^1$ functions?

Comment: [Closed range](https://msp.org/pjm/1984/110-2/pjm-v110-n2-p01-s.pdf)

Comment: @rumathe Sorry but I did not quite follow. It seems that this article fixed the right operand as $f$ and discussed the non-closeness in the sense of topology of the range of convolution with $f$, but I would like to know about the range of convolution in general. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Even though the Fourier transform elegantly expresses convolution as multiplication, the fact that $\mathcal{F}(L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)) \subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ introduces potential mismatches. Not every function in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ arises as the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function. If we want to argue by transforming a combination of convolutions in the equation into the Fourier domain, then solving for $\mathcal{F}(f)$ and $\mathcal{F}(g)$, a problem emerges. Even if those solutions exist in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, their inverse Fourier transforms might not land back in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Comment: @rumathe Yes, and that's also my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,
$$
L^1(\Bbb{R^d}) \ast L^1(\Bbb{R^d}) = L^1(\Bbb{R^d}),
$$
which is thus in particular a vector space.

This follows from the Cohen-Hewitt factorization theorem. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Hewitt_factorization_theorem) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/48662324?seq=1) for details.

Comment: Thanks! The result is interesting.